# SQL::Abstract::Limit failing at OR logic

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm trying to create an `OR` logic query using [`Class::DBI`](http://search.cpan.org/~tmtm/Class-DBI-v3.0.17/lib/Class/DBI.pm)/[`Class::DBI::AbstractSearch`](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Class-DBI-AbstractSearch-0.07/lib/Class/DBI/AbstractSearch.pm).  My code looks something like this:

```
my $results = Example::CDBI::Quote->search_where(
    {   field_1 => {'like', $search_string},
        field_2 => {'like', $search_string}},
    {logic => 'or'}
);
```

According to [the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Class-DBI-AbstractSearch-0.07/lib/Class/DBI/AbstractSearch.pm#METHODS) this should work.  It says that the information is passed to [`SQL::Abstract::Limit`](http://search.cpan.org/~davebaird/SQL-Abstract-Limit-0.141/lib/SQL/Abstract/Limit.pm), which shows as taking the `logic` parameter.  Unfortunately, MySQL shows the following in the query log (edited for brevity, and assuming a search of "123"):

```
SELECT * FROM quote WHERE ((field_1 LIKE '123' AND field_2 LIKE '123' ))
```

I have trying changing `'or'` to `'OR'` (silly, but worth a shot) which did not work.  I also tried hunting down the logic in `SQL::Abstract::Limit`, but this operator is being passed to `SQL::Abstract` instead.

How do I get `SQL::Abstract::Limit` to accept `OR` logic from `Class::DBI`?

**How `Class::DBI` calls `SQL::Abstract::Limit`**
I was able to determine how `SQL::Abstract::Limit` is being constructed.  I put values in instead of the variable names so it is easier to read.

```
my $sql = SQL::Abstract::Limit->new({'logic' => 'OR'});
my($phrase, @bind) = $sql->where(
    {'field_1'=>{'like' => '123'},'field_2'=>{'like'=>'123'}},
    undef, undef, undef);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply OR locally like this:

```
use SQL::Abstract;

my $sql = SQL::Abstract->new;
my ($stmt, @bind) = $sql->where(
    { -or => [ { field_1 => { 'like', 'John' }},
               { field_2 => { 'like', 'John' }},
             ],
    }, []);
```

gives in `$stmt`:

```
WHERE ( ( field_1 LIKE ? OR field_2 LIKE ? ) )
```

The `logic` property can be set in `SQL::Abstract` constructor, but I don't have idea how to propagate from `Class::DBI`.

**Edit**: I don't know if it is bug or feature, but it the operators changed by `logic` clause seems apply only when you define with arrayrefs. With hashrefs, you get always AND:

```
my $sql_and = SQL::Abstract::Limit->new(logic => 'AND');
my $sql_or  = SQL::Abstract::Limit->new(logic => 'OR');

say $sql_and->where(['field_1'=>{'like' => '123'},'field_2'=>{'like'=>'123'}]);  
# WHERE ( ( field_1 LIKE ? AND field_2 LIKE ? ) )

say $sql_or->where (['field_1'=>{'like' => '123'},'field_2'=>{'like'=>'123'}]);  
# WHERE ( ( field_1 LIKE ? OR field_2 LIKE ? ) )
```

Or, to work with `Class::DBI`:

```
my $results = Example::CDBI::Quote->search_where(
    [   field_1 => {'like', $search_string},
        field_2 => {'like', $search_string}],
    {logic => 'or'}
);
```

Comment: I added a bit of details as to how Class::DBI is calling SQL::Abstract and ::Limit.

Comment: @Jack M. - seems like `logic` works only for arrayrefs. See edited answer.

Comment: You were correct.  That seems like such an odd change to be made to SQL::Abstract.  Thank you!

Comment: @Jack M. - btw, it looks like OR is default for arrayrefs, so `logic => 'or'` can be left out.